# Flutter Dart - How to get data from one class to another class

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am new to flutter framework. I made a app to visualize the data through SF slider widget.

Here is my code, I want to get somehow the data to my class which is in **main.dart file** from other class which is in **widgets.dart file**

**main.dart file**

```
//import 'dart:math';
//import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'widgets.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_sliders/sliders.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/gauges.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
          }),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
} 

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ScanResultTile jamJam = new ScanResultTile();
  double _value = 40.0;
  double _valueP = 940.0;
  double _valueH = 54.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```

In the class **_MyHomePageState** I want to get the data *result* from below file class **ScanResultTile** Any suggestion, how can I do this ?

**widgets.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
//import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'dart:convert';

class ScanResultTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScanResultTile({Key key, this.result, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  final ScanResult result;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  Widget _buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    if (result.device.name.length > 0) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            result.device.name,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          Text(
            result.device.id.toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
          )
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Text(result.device.id.toString());
    }
  }

  Widget _buildAdvRow(BuildContext context, String title, String value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 4.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
          SizedBox(
            width: 12.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              value,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .caption
                  ?.apply(color: Colors.black),
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
String getData(String hexData) {
    List<String> myData = hexData.split(',');
    if (myData[0] == '61') {
      String temp = (myData[2] + myData[3] + myData[4] + myData[5]);
      String fTemp = temp.replaceAll(' ', '');
      String tNum = ((int.parse(fTemp, radix: 16)) / 100).toString();

      String pres = (myData[7] + myData[8] + myData[9]);
      String fPres = pres.replaceAll(' ', '');
      String pNum = ((int.parse(fPres, radix: 16)) / 100).toString();

      String rh = (myData[11] + myData[12] + myData[13]);
      String frh = rh.replaceAll(' ', '');
      String rhNum = ((int.parse(frh, radix: 16)) / 1024).toString();

      String result = 'Temp: $tNum deg C, Pres: $pNum hPa, RH $rhNum %';

      return result;
    }return "Garuda"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to read the value of the result property in the `jamJam` variable? if so: `jamJam.result`, and I recommend you follow a tutorial on the dart language and flutter before you begin developing an app

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to get the result which is inside the function **getData** . I follow the Dart documentation, but I am bit unclear how to get the data which is inside a function with arguments. Ex in my case **String getData(String hexData)**. This function is returning a **result** That's what I am interested to get in **main.dart file class**

Comment: why not just call the function within main? `final result = getData(hexData);`, you could also cut the function from one file to main, or is there a reason for the function to be in the widgets.dart file specifically?

Comment: @h8moss, thank you again, there is no reason for writing a function in widgets,dart file. Lets say for instance I wrote the **getData** function in **main.dart file**  but even how can we call i access the variable **result** inside getData function ?

Comment: I am really sorry, I still have trouble understanding your question. As I stated, the way to get the result from in getData would be to call getData, like this: `final result = getData(hexData);`, is that not what you want?